# Finding the area between : $\frac{\pi}{3}\leq \theta \leq \frac{2 \pi}{3}, 0 \leq r \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> $$\iint dx \,dy $$
>   I need to find the area between : $\frac{\pi}{3}\leq \theta \leq \frac{2 \pi}{3}, 0 \leq r \leq 1$

**My attempt:**
Using Fubini's theorem
Using double integral:

$$\int\limits_{y=\frac{\pi}{3}}^{y=\frac{2\pi}{3}}\left[~\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1} dx \right]dy=\int\limits_{y=\frac{\pi}{3}}^{y=\frac{2\pi}{3}} 1 \,dy=\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{3}=\boxed{\color{red} {\frac{\pi}{3}}} $$

> Is it correct?

Comment: it is not so clear to me what is the area you are trying to calculate. but if I understand correctly , that the area , which is $1/6$ of the unit circle. so the answer in that case is $\pi / 6$. would you elaborate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that the region is given in polar coordinates, not in rectangular coordinates, so ${\rm d}A = r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta$ should be used, and not ${\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$ (unless you want to suffer with stuff like $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, etc). Let $S$ be the desired sector. We actually have $$\iint_S {\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = \int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\int_0^1 r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta = \frac
\pi 3 \cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\pi}{6},$$as this is the area of the sector (the arc is of $\pi/3$ radians and the radius is $1$):

[image]

Comment: How this pic was drawn ?

Comment: I used [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/).

Comment: thanks. I just wondered .. something seem strange here... the arc CB should be the same len as the arc B to (1,0). (which is clearly larger in this pic).

Comment: I'll fix it, gimme two minutes. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Done, better now.